Keycloak 24.x Performance issue
We've implemented Keycloak into our project for user authentication, meticulously following the deployment guidelines outlined here.
Despite experimenting with various configurations, we're encountering persistent issues. Initially, following a fresh deployment or after restarting the Keycloak pods, when subjected to a load of 20 concurrent users per second for 5 minutes, Keycloak can reliably handle 30-35 tokens per second. However, over time, performance degrades, dropping to 8-9 tokens per second. Eventually, this decline culminates in errors such as closedChannelException and IOException.

We've monitored CPU and memory usage to investigate potential performance limitations but have found that it consistently operates below 50% of its allocated capacity before performance degradation occurs and exceptions are thrown.
Here we have our deployment configuration:
KC_DB_POOL_INITIAL_SIZE : 20
KC_DB_POOL_MAX_SIZE : 20
KC_DB_POOL_MIN_SIZE : 20
KC_DB_URL_PROPERTIES : ;trustServerCertificate=true;encrypt=true;
KC_HTTP_MAX_QUEUED_REQUESTS : 500
KC_LOG_LEVEL : INFO,org.infinispan:INFO,org.jgroups:INFO
KC_PROXY : edge
KC_HTTP_POOL_MAX_THREADS: 20
KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED : false

Could you suggest areas we should investigate to enhance performance or any recommended presets for our deployment configuration?

What OS are you on? How did you monitor CPU and memory usage? What do you mean by "it consistently operates below 50% of its allocated capacity"? If you're on Linux, what is the PSS usage of the top-level java process, and what is the total RAM available (not 'free')? And what are your PSI (Pressure Stall) readings? What are you running on - bare metal, VPS, another VM of some sort?

Keycloak has been deployed within a Kubernetes cluster hosted on an Ubuntu VM. Monitoring of CPU and memory utilization has been conducted using Grafana and OpenLens. Each Keycloak pod has been allocated 5 CPU cores, yet during operation, Keycloak predominantly utilizes no more than 2 cores, leaving the remaining 3 cores largely idle. @EML

Answer: Upgrade to Keycloak 25
Keycloak 24.x introduced an update to its hashing algorithm, we went from PBKDF2-SHA1 in Keycloak 23 with 27K iterations to PBKDF2-SHA512 with over 210K at the cost of an almost 1 times increase in CPU usage.
With keycloak 25, we now have the argon2 algorithm, which reduces greatly the CPU usage for hashing passwords.
